# How to make a shape "grow" from the bottom up in CSS animations, and set the animation using a CSS variable

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a css cylinder (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8d0w93zo/1/)) that looks like this:

[image]

I wish to project it on the screen with a 5 sec animation where it 'grows' bottom up. I've tried numerous orientations with 'keyframes' but failed to achieve the desired result.

```css
.tank {
    position:relative;
    width:12px;
    height: var(--h,2px);
    bottom: var(--h,2px);
    background-color:var(--c,#444); 
    opacity: 0.85;
    animation: move-me-up 5s;
}
.tank:before {
    width: 12px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:var(--s,#666);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:-2.5px;
    
}
.tank:after {
    width: 12px;
    height: var(--h,2px);
    background-color:var(--c,#444);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:1px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: -1;    
    
}


@keyframes move-me-up {
  0% {
    height: 2px;
  }
 
  100% {
    height: var(--h,2px);
  }
}
```

```html
<BR><BR><BR><BR>
<BR><BR><BR><BR>
<div class="tank" style="--h:120px;--c:#186b03;--s:#50d130"></div>
```

Also, I was wondering how to define this animation as optional in the creation of the div with something like `include_animation: true/false`:

Example (pseudo)

```
<div class="tank" style="--h:120px;--c:#186b05;--s:#50d135; include_animation:true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. To add the animation as a variable**: You cannot pass in a setting like `include_animation:true`, however what we *can* do is pass in a valid value for the animation property and use it.

We could create a variable e.g. `--animation` and set its value to the animation we want to run, e.g. `--animation:move-me-up`. This means you need to specify the exact name of the animation, so it might be easier to run the animation by default, and set the variable to `none` to *prevent* the animation from running, e.g.:

```
.tank {
    /* move-me-up is the default animation. 
       Set --animation to "none" for no animation, 
       or you could even set another animation name */
    animation-name: var(--animation, move-me-up);
    animation-duration: 5s;
    /* Rest of the CSS... */
}
```

You can see this working in the example in the next section.

---

**2. Getting the animation to work**: The reason you can't see the `animation` in your jsfiddle, is because the CSS for `.tank:after` is showing the full tank so the animation is being hidden. You can see it working if you remove this line from the CSS:

```
.tank:after {
    /* other CSS.. */
    background-color:var(--c,#444); /* Remove this line */
}
```

However now the animation will start at the top and grow down the height of the full element is changing and it will expand down by default, so we need to do step 3.

---

**3. Make the animation "grow" from the bottom** We can do this quite easily in the `keyframes`, by making the value for `top` the same as `bottom` at the start and having it finish at `top:0`:

```
@keyframes move-me-up {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    top: var(--h,2px);   /* the top of the tank starts at the bottom */
  }
  100% {
    height: var(--h,2px);  
    top: 0;              /* when it finishes, top is at 0 (i.e. the top of the parent) */
  }
}
```

**Working Example of tank growing from the bottom, and also setting no animation using a variable**

```css
.tank {
    position:relative;
    width:12px;
    height: var(--h,2px);
    background-color:var(--c,#444); 
    opacity: 0.85;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

    /* ADD THE ANIMATION. 
    move-me-up is the default animation. 
    set --animation to "none" for no animation, 
    or you could even set another animation name */
    animation-name: var(--animation, move-me-up);
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

.tank:before {
    width: 12px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:var(--s,#666);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:-2.5px;
}

.tank:after {
    width: 12px;
    height: var(--h,2px);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:1px;
    z-index: -1;      
}


@keyframes move-me-up {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    top: var(--h,2px);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
 
  100% {
    height: var(--h,2px); 
    top: 0;
  }
}


/* for displaying the example only */
.tank { float:left; margin-right: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="tank" style="--h:120px;--c:#186b05;--s:#50d135;"></div>

<div class="tank" style="--h:120px;--c:#186b05;--s:#50d135; --animation:none"></div>
```

**4. Alternative: Fill in an empty tank from the bottom**: if you wanted to show an "empty" tank and have it fill from the bottom, you can do it as follows:

We make the `tank` class the container and the `:after` pseudo element the main "fill" by moving the background and animation from `.tank` to `.tank:after`, and also setting `bottom: 0` to start at the bottom:

```
.tank {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); /* Add this */
    /* Rest of the CSS...*/
}
.tank:after {
    bottom: 0;                         /* Start at the bottom and grow up */
    background-color: var(--c, #444);  /* moved from .tank to give this element has the "fill" */
    animation: move-me-up 5s;          /* moved from .tank to animate the fill */
    /* Rest of the CSS...*/
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.tank {
  position: relative;
  width: 12px;
  height: var(--h, 2px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.tank:before {
  width: 12px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: var(--s, #666);
  -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
  border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -2.5px;
}

.tank:after {
  width: 12px;
  height: var(--h, 2px);
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;

  -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
  border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;

  background-color: var(--c, #444);   /* this element has the "fill" */
  bottom: 0;                          /* Start at the bottom and grow up */

  /* ADD THE ANIMATION. 
  move-me-up is the default animation. 
  set --animation to "none" for no animation, 
  or you could even set another animation name */
  animation-name: var(--animation, move-me-up);
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes move-me-up {
  0% {
    height: 2px;
  }
  100% {
    height: var(--h, 2px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tank" style="--h:120px;--c:#186b05;--s:#50d135;"></div>
```

Comment: FluffyKitten = Awesome. THANK YOU!